# How to populate a sql db with t.decimal precision and scale via rails c

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, decimal

```
t.decimal  "eur",        precision: 8,  scale: 2
```

This is my Row in the Database table (name is wallet). How can I populate it with data in the rails console?

I have tried

`wallet.eur=10` Ok this one is to easy and doesnt work.

`wallet.eur=BigDecimal.new('154.00')` This one throws something like 
 `=> #<BigDecimal:56cadb8,'0.154E3',9(18)>` But i cant save it and will stay at 0.0.

Any Idea or suggestion?

Comment: I just tried it and can save it. To get something more human readable, try calling `to_f` on the result: `wallet.eur.to_f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in rails facilities, check the [NumberHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) documentation for examples.

Use this code to add the migration:

```
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

and then use this method:

```
number_to_currency(price, :unit => "€")
```

If you've got an NoMethodError add this line:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

Comment: rails console gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'number_to_currency'` ... Edit: Ok seems this helper is only available for the views.

Comment: @DennyMueller I've updated the answer with a necessary include.

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with currency maybe money-rails gem might be worthwhile?

Or something similar just using an integer and storing it in pence/cents and creating helpers to display it.

Plays much nicer than using decimal or worse float.